# angle sum for triangle on helicoid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given the helicoid
$$ \boldsymbol{r} = (u\sin v, u\cos v,v)$$
in three-dimensional Euclidean space,
consider the triangle $T$ defined by
$$ 0 \leq u \leq \sinh v, \qquad 0 \leq v \leq v_0.$$

The angles of the triangle are $\theta_1=\pi/4=\theta_2,\ \theta_3=\pi/2.$

Question: is the triangle geodesic? For a geodesic triangle, we have the equality
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Total_curvature)
$$ \sum_{i=1}^3 \theta_i - \pi = \int_T K \ \mathrm{d}A,$$
and given that the Gaussian curvature is $K=-1/(u^2+1)^2$ using the above data we get
$$0 = \log\cosh v_0.$$
So the answer would seem to be NO: is that OK ?

Comment: I don't know whether the sides of your triangle are geodesics on the helicoid; see the link given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262393/geodesic-of-helicoid   . At any rate you can compute their geodesic curvature, and then Gauss' formula should hold true.

Comment: Thanks; so it is not a geodesic triangle, likely; can you expand on your last statement?

Comment: Where you found the formula to compute $K$ in terms of the parameters there you should also find formulas for $\kappa_g$ along a curve $t\mapsto{\bf r}\bigl(u(t),v(t)\bigr)$.